# Передать переменную на другую страницу

Tags: php

Всем привет, я только изучил php, сделал регистрацию, авторизацию, но как сделать так, чтоб при переходе на другую страницу данные (например масив с никнеймом, ID пользователя который вошел, булевскую переменную(авторизирован или нет))? помогите плз) в интернете искал но наверное похо.

да нет кода пока что..) ну вот пример -

```
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mybase");
            $mysqli -> query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

            $query = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = 
'".$mysqli -> escape_string ($login)."'");
            echo $mysqli->error;
            global $row;
            $row = $query->fetch_assoc();

            if (isset($row)) {

                if (in_array($login, $row)) {

                    if ($row['password'] == md5($password)) {
                        $GLOBALS["is_logged"] = true;
                        global $accessed;
                        $accessed = $GLOBALS["row"];

                    }
                    if ($row['password'] !== md5($password)) {
                        $error_password = 'write true password!';
                        $_SESSION['password'] = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!isset($row)) {
                $error_login = 'unknown login!';
                $_SESSION['login'] = "";
                $_SESSION['password'] = "";
            }


            $mysqli->close();

            }
        }
        $_SESSION["is_logged"] = $is_logged;
        $_SESSION["accessed"] = $accessed;
```

надо сделать так чтоб при открытии например lottary.php  я мог использовать переменные, созданые в этом коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас же уже используется массив сессии, пишите в него все необходимые переменные, и используйте на нужных вам страничках. 
Стартуете сессию 
session_start(); 
и обращаетесь к нужному элементу массива $_SESSION

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php